# Lung Detection and Segmentation in X Ray Image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, detection, thresholding

I'm a beginner in image processing and I have to create a segmentation algorithm to detect lungs from an image .
Image given :

[image]

And after removing the noise from the image and applying a threshold the image should look like this :
[image]

I would like to know if there is a specific approach that is used for lung detection and segmentation .

I `subtract the background` from the image , then apply the `gamma function` and then the `median` filter . Afterwards I perform `thresholding`

This is my algorithm so far in `java` with `imagej`  and I need a cleaner result :

```
            IJ.run(imp2, "Remove Outliers...", "radius=100 threshold=50 which=Dark"); //remove dark noise square
                    IJ.run(imp2, "Gamma...", "value=0.76"); //appply gamma function 
                   IJ.run(imp2, "Subtract Background...", "rolling=2000 light"); //subtract bg 
                   IJ.run(imp2, "Median...", "radius=20"); //Apply median filter 
                   IJ.run(imp2, "Auto Threshold", "method=Li white"); //Li method for thresholding 
                   IJ.run(imp2, "Invert", "");
                 imp2.show();
```

Image after algorithm :

[image]

. I would appreciate your help .

Comment: also remarking it here: the ground truth mask shows signs of being a polygon of few vertices, likely some human defined these points. don't expect to come close to this with simple methods.

Comment: For lung detection I see if the object is breathing—- if it is breathing I know there is a lung in it. (Sorry bad joke- couldn’t resist!)